# Why is the state initially not displaying?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuex

I'm learning out Vue and Vuex.

I have some data defined in my store like so:

```
export const store = new Vuex.store({
  state: {
    partnership: "default",
  }
});
```

and my template to display the data:

```
<span>{{$store.state.partnership}}</span>
```

I was expecting to see "default" initially but it only displays after a change occurs:

**Initially**

[image: ]1]

```
methods:{
  updateValue(){
    this.$store.state.partnership = "edited";
  }
}
```

**After updating the value**

[image]

Why is the default value not being displayed? or what am I not doing correct?

Comment: isn't recommended edit state directly, you should do it using mutations for synchronous changes, and actions for asynchronous changes of state.

Comment: The default value should display. Can you provide a snippet on CodeSandbox so we can help you on something explicit ?

Comment: Possible typo... `export const store = new Vuex.store({` should be `Vuex.Store`.